# WinJS Creating multiple folders

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

Okay, so I'm trying to create a deep folder structure and I'm looping through duplicate folder names and creating promises like this:

```
var promises = [];
_.each(files, function (file) {
    promises.push(localFolder
        .createFolderAsync(folder1Name, Windows.Storage.NameCollisionOption.OpenIfExists)
        .then(function (folder1) {
            return folder1.createFolderAsync(folder2Name, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        })
        .then(function (folder2) {
            return folder2.createFileAsync(fileName, Windows.Storage.NameCollisionOption.replaceExisting)
        })
    );
});

return WinJS.Promise.join(promises);
```

The problem is the duplicate folders, I thought OpenIfExists would just return the existing folders, but instead I end up with folders called "folder1Name (1)", "folder1Name (2)", etc. Using FailIfExists also is not failing, so I suspect there's something wrong with my promise chain.

Can anyone pinpoint what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of the first createFolderAsync call should be Windows.Storage.**CreationCollisionOption**.openIfExists instead of NameCollisionOption.

```
var promises = [];
_.each(files, function (file) {
    promises.push(localFolder
        .createFolderAsync(folder1Name, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.openIfExists)
        .then(function (folder1) {
            return folder1.createFolderAsync(folder2Name, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.openIfExists);
        })
        .then(function (folder2) {
            return folder2.createFileAsync(fileName, Windows.Storage.NameCollisionOption.replaceExisting)
        })
    );
});

return WinJS.Promise.join(promises);
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch! In addition to this I had to use non-capital letters, although the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.creationcollisionoption.aspx) gives both as options

Comment: In the documentation, when you see something like OpenIfExists | openIfExists, it's indicating that C++/C#/VB use the former and JavaScript uses the latter. That is, JavaScript always uses camel casing for properties and methods, and all lowercase for events. This is how WinRT gets projected into JavaScript, and is essential for knowing when you read the docs. JavaScript as a language is unfortunately very unforgiving here, as the wrong casing will resolve to undefined and an API will often ignore an invalid arg value like that.

Comment: updated the casing... I have to check, but I believe intellisense gave me the uppercase version...

Comment: Your casing in the sample code above looks correct. I'm responding to usagidon's comment specifically.

Comment: I updated the sample :) it was wrong... I checked the intellisense too, which does the lowercase version. Something must have gone wrong copying... Anyway, thanks for the about the documentation.